# Prove that there is an integer $b$ greater than an integer $a$, such that $a + b$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Let's represent the perfect square by $c^2$.
Then:

$a + b = c^2$

$b = c^2 - a$.

Since, by definition, $c^2$ is an integer, $a$ is an integer and the subtraction of two integers yields an integer, $b$ exists and is an integer.

That is my solution, but it seems too simplistic. Could you please correct my proof or suggest a new one?

Comment: You started by assuming what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Is $b=a^2-a$ a good choice?

Comment: You haven't proven that $b > a$. Other than that, yes, this looks like a good start.

Comment: @HowDoIMath: that only works for $a\ge 3$

Comment: @Henry, yeah, I know. It was meant as a place to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given $a\in{\mathbb Z}$ the number $(a+1)^2$ is a square and sufficiently $>a$. Therefore let's try
$$b:=(a+1)^2-a\in{\mathbb Z}\ .$$
Then $a+b$ is a square, and
$$b-a=a^2+1>0\ ,$$
as required.